# move_uploaded_file() returning false

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I have been uploading a file for last few hours. But always stuck at this point.

***here is my controller function for upload***:

```
function upload()
{
    echo $targetPath = site_url('/uploads'); 
    echo "<br />";
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    if (!(($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")))
    {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists($targetPath.'/'.$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$targetPath.'/'. $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo "Stored in: " .$targetPath.'/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "not uploaded";
            }
        }
    }
```

***and here is the output :***

```
http://localhost/sites/public_html/site/uploads 
image/jpegUpload: 1468716_668135866543165_1899878158_n.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 57.09375 kB
Temp file: C:\wamp\tmp\phpC390.tmp
not uploaded
```

Everything is going fine.

**But its just not UPLOADING at desired location. What could be wrong ?**

Comment: Does PHP have write permissions on the folder.

Comment: Yes it has.. but still its not working :/

Comment: Do a `print_r($_FILES)`. Specifically, check that `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` equals 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `move_uploaded_file` to an HTTP destination; it must be a local filesystem path.

Your `$targetPath` must be something like `c:\wamp\www\sites\public_html\...` instead.

Comment: D'oh. I didn't understand he was doing that. Good catch.